# How can I make the application package available to the tests, when using py.test?

Tags: python, testing, module, pytest

Suppose I'm writing a test. Obviously it is testing my app, so I need to import the app package somehow into the test script. The directory structure is this:

```
root/
    app/
        __init__.py
        somemodule.py
    tests/
        my_test.py
```

And I run the tests like so:

```
cd tests
py.test # runs all the tests in the current directory
```

The question is: How should I import the application modules in my test modules?

In `my_test.py`, I tried doing `from .. import app`. This gives me an error `Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import.`

What is the standard way to accomplish this?

EDIT: Please note I edited the question to refer specifically to the `py.test` tool.

Comment: You could probably get away with just adding `root/` to the PYTHONPATH (either through `sys.path` or with the environment variable), then inside of my_test.py you should be able to do `import app.somemodule as foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to make it run by properly configuring your py.test.

Add your module to your `app/__init__.py` the following line

```
from .somemodule import MyClass # or whatever ur class is called
```

Create a file called `conftest.py` in your **main** folder. You can leave it empty but it is used by py.test to find out the project path. Inside you can run some py.test initialization like adding [fixtures](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html).

In your `my_test.py` you will be able now to call

```
from app import MyClass
```

Now from your **main** folder you can finally:

```
py.test tests/test.py
```

This has worked for me. I think py.test has a way to include modules since you are probably not able to achieve the same without it. At least if I did not use py.test I would stick to modifying my PYTHONPATH to point to my application path.

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify py.test manipylates the `sys.path` for the testing session to include the root directory. Py.test identify the root path by using the conftest.py file. The root path is then added to the system path and used for testing.

You are indeed able to run:

```
py.test tests/test.py
```

and this would also work:

```
cd..
py.test rootTest/tests/test.py
```

Comment: Is `conftest.py` run by `py.test`? If so, did you mean I should `import app` in there (not `import pytest`)?

Comment: no i really meant import pytest. Conftest is run by py.test

Comment: What does importing `pytest` in `conftest.py` do?

Comment: Actually nothing, but the file conftest.py must be there. You can import pytest if u want to run some pytest configuration for all tests. I will update my answer for clarity.

Comment: Do you think maybe pytest adds any folder with a conftest.py file to sys.path? Otherwise how can this work?

Comment: Indeed it does. Pytest scans for conftest.py and uses that location as root path. The root path is always added to PYTHONPATH therefore the module to be tested can be correctly imported.